# Regex for french mobile number that validate for ( +, - and " "(blank spance")

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on validation french mobile number. I need regex for french mobile number that regex validate signs like + (plus), -(dash) and blank space.

I need to validate patterns like,

```
 +XX XX XX XX XX XX
 +XX XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
 +XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
 +XX.XX.XX.XX.XX.XX
 +XX XX.XX.XX.XX.XX
```

Here X is digit( 0 to 9)

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `\+\d{2}(?:[ .-]\d{2}){5}`

Comment: Hello @ctwheels it's working. but not match like `+XX.XX-XX-XX-XX-XX` , `XX XX XX XX-XX.XX`

Comment: Please see the answer I posted below. I cover that topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first regex below will match any variations without uniform number separators: That means `+00 00.00-00.00 00` is valid. If that's not the intention, you can use the second or third regex pattern below.

```
\+\d{2}(?:[ .-]\d{2}){5}
\+\d{2}(?:(?:-\d{2}){5}|(?:\.\d{2}){5}|(?: \d{2}){5}| \d{2}(?:-\d{2}){4}| \d{2}(?:\.\d{2}){4})
\+\d{2}(?: \d{2}([ .-])\d{2}(?:\1\d{2}){3}|([ .-])\d{2}(?:\2\d{2}){4})
```

- `\+` Match `+` literally
- `\d{2}` Match exactly two digits
- `(?:[ .-]\d{2}){5}` Match the following exactly 5 times

  - `[ .-]` Match any character in the set
  - `\d{2}` Match any digit exactly twice

```js
var t = ['+00 00 00 00 00 00','+00 00-00-00-00-00','+00-00-00-00-00-00','+00.00.00.00.00.00','+00 00.00.00.00.00']
var r = /\+\d{2}(?:[ .-]\d{2}){5}/

t.forEach(function(n){
  if(r.test(n)) console.log(n)
})
```